# zanussi is not heating up one hob glass

Tags: electrical

zanussi zev6240fba, one of hob won't heat up even it reaches 9
any idea to fix it?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YofMpdFk0M

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like it's broken, but without more info we couldn't tell you why. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: replace the defective part

Comment: which one is defective?how do i khow defective one is?